# Change heights of elements dynamically - Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I have 2 div elements that are connected, in the left one I have list of images, and in the right one I have details of each image. I open the right div on clicking on image, and it has absolute position, but then I get into a problem.

I need to calculate heights of those 2 divs, so I always have the same height - each time i click something, change something... (I can have only one image in the left div and it has a lot of information so the right div's height is bigger, or I can have 100 images on the left so left height is bigger). This is what I tried, but it doesn't work good enough:

```
leftHeight: number;
rightHeight: number;

ngDoCheck() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 1336 && this.openDetails) {
      this.chRef.detectChanges();
      if (this.leftElement.nativeElement.clientHeight > this.rightElement.nativeElement.clientHeight) {
        this.rightHeight = this.leftElement.nativeElement.clientHeight;
      } else {
        this.leftHeight = this.rightElement.nativeElement.clientHeight;
      }
      this.chRef.detectChanges();

    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">

 <div class="left-part" #leftElement [style.height.px]="leftHeight - 40">
  <!-- some ngFor is here with images -->
 </div>

 <div [@focusPanel]='smallScreen' *ngIf="openDetails" #rightElement class="right-part" [style.height.px]="rightHeight - 65">
<!-- some details of each image -->
 </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestion on what to try, what else to do?

EDIT: This semi-works, I set the height of elements at start, but it doesn't change the height after it, doesn't calculate again

Comment: Why not just fix their height by using `vh` in CSS and adding a scroll for any overflow content ?

Comment: Sounds to me that it this is  CSS (not angular) issue... look here: http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/ , you will find that one way making 2 divs equall height is by set the container "display" propery to "flex" and "align-content" to be "stretch"

Comment: @happyZZR1400 not really, if the element position is absolute, it will not take the height of sibling element, I need to calculate it on every change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will help, but have you try to call to your function ngDoCheck in ngAfterViewChecked event?

It shoul'd be something similar to this:

```
 export class YourComponent implements AfterViewChecked {

    constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    ngAfterViewChecked() {
       this.ngDoCheck();
    }
```

Comment: Not working :/ The thing is, I calculate the height at start, but it is not working after it, doesn't recalculate it on change

Comment: Try not to calculate the height at start but inside the ngAfterViewChecked , here needs to be all the initialization stuff .

Comment: It doesn't work i get the initial heights calculated fine, but it doesn't continue calculating, it won't recalculate the height, even though when i put breakpoint in chrome console it triggers every time.. weird interraction

Comment: Try to replace nativeElement with renderer2. With renderer2 we can add and remove CSS classes, styles and HTML attributes. See https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

Comment: i.e.:  this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'height', value)

Comment: Tried this as well but nothing happens, not even at the start, I'll try it again maybe i messed up smth

Answer (score -1):

You can set scroll bars on right div. Simply add to css:

```
.scrollBarClass {
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

and then in your right div add:

```
<div class="scrollBarClass"> </div>
```

Edited answer:

If you have dinamicaly set height of both div's, then simply set

```
<div class="scrollBarClass"> </div>
```

on both divs, and you will have scroll if they become too large.

Comment: I can't set heights like that, content can have different heights all the time.

Comment: Then use `[ngStyle]="{'max-height': maxHeight()}" `and in component set max-height dinamicaly depending on height of your left div

Comment: And by the way you asked for suggestion, you got one and in return you downvoted my answer???? The fact that you didn't liked my answer, doesn't mean that it is not usefull.